# Access data from inside a function in the global scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, global

I'm still learning JS and I'm currently struggling with this problem. I want to be able to access the data from `ordArray` in the global scope. How do I do this ? I've tried with returns but struggling to solve it.

```
const startOrd = function() {
    const ordArray = [];
    val = document.getElementById("val_ord").value;
    ordArray.push(val)
    console.log(ordArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create ordArray outside of the function :)

```
const ordArray = [];
const startOrd = function () {
  val = document.getElementById("val_ord").value;
  ordArray.push(val)
  console.log(ordArray)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare/initialize the array outside of the function.

```
const ordArray = [];

const startOrd = function() {
    val = document.getElementById("val_ord").value;
    ordArray.push(val)
    console.log(ordArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, Only thing you want is *I've tried with returns but struggling to solve it*

Demo **:**

```js
const startOrd = function() {
    const ordArray = [];
    const val = document.getElementById("val_ord").value;
    ordArray.push(val)
    return ordArray;
};

console.log(startOrd());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val_ord" value="abcd"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Constants are `block-scoped`, when you create variable in function you dont access to variable out side the function.

please follow the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

I think, This writing code method is more better:

```
var ordArray = [];
let startOrd = (elem) => elem?.value;
let targetElem = document.getElementById("val_ord");
ordArray.push(startOrd(targetElem));
```

Comment: Write the reason for the negative score. I will be happy if I learn something new.